Run length encoding for nested datatypes in BigQuery
I'm working on a data model in BigQuery where I'm storing arrays of structs in one of my columns. The data in this column gets duplicated several times since the data model is designed to store redundant records. I wanted to know if BigQuery applies run length encoding even to nested data types for compression.
I've tried checking the docs I couldn't find any info about this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Have a good read of this article AND the associated paper ...
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/bigquery/inside-capacitor-bigquerys-next-generation-columnar-storage-format
This will provide knowledge on "Capacitor" which is the data format that BigQuery uses to store table data.

@Kolban thanks for the pointer, it helps a ton
